# Android: Custom List View is not working properly

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

My apologies for not providing a proper source code.

basically what I have in my list view xml layout  is:

- listleave.xml
- leaveSummary.xml
- leavedB
- Custom Adapter
- ApplyLeave

I'm creating an app where I have a list view and when I'm running my app I'm getting an error in Locgat.

```
Caused by:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual 
method 'void 
android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null 
object reference
at com.example.huzai.civilsoft1.ApplyLeave.loadDataInListView(ApplyLeave.java:258 )
 at com.example.huzai.civilsoft1.ApplyLeave.onCreate(ApplyLeave.java:84)
```

In the line *loadDataInListView* when I'm not commenting `l1.setAdapter(customAdapter);` the app crashes but when I'm commenting it works properly.

Result of  not commenting: `l1.setAdapter(customAdapter);`

[image]

1. ApplyLeave Activity

   ```
   public class ApplyLeave extends AppCompatActivity {
   LeaveService myDb;
   //Declaration EditTexts
   EditText editstartDate;
   EditText   editendDate;
   DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
   CheckBox checkgoingAbroad;
   Spinner spinnertypess;
   Spinner editleavess;
   EditText editremarks;
   EditText editnoOfDays1;
   TextView noOfDays;
   TextView endd;
   Button btnApply;
   Button addfield;
   Button deletefield;
   LinearLayout parentlinearlayout;
   ListView l1;
   ArrayList<Leave> arrayList;
   CustomAdapter customAdapter;
   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_apply_leave);
   myDb = new LeaveService (this);
    checkgoingAbroad =(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.GoingAbroad);
   spinnertypess = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.types);
   editleavess = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Leaves);
   editremarks = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reason);
   editnoOfDays1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.noOfDays);
   parentlinearlayout = 
   (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent_linear_layout);
   addfield = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addField);
   deletefield = (Button)findViewById(R.id.removeField);
   endd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
   l1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.leaveApplicationSummary);
   btnApply = (Button)findViewById(R.id.apply);
   AddData();
   arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
   loadDataInListView();

    //Created a method for loadDataInListView
   private void loadDataInListView() {
       arrayList = myDb.getAllData();
       customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,arrayList);
       l1.setAdapter(customAdapter);
       customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   private void AddData() {
       btnApply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
           boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData("", checkgoingAbroad.toString(), spinnertypess.toString(), editleavess.toString(), editnoOfDays1.getText().toString(), editstartDate.getText().toString(), editendDate.getText().toString(), editremarks.getText().toString());
           if (isInserted == true){

               Toast.makeText(ApplyLeave.this, "Data Inserted Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(ApplyLeave.this, "Data Not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       }
   });
   ```

   }

Result of commenting:  `//l1.setAdapter(customAdapter);`

[image]

2. CustomAdapter class

   ```
   public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   Context context;

   ArrayList<Leave> arrayList;

   public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Leave>arraylist) {

   this.context = context;

   this.arrayList = arraylist;

   }
   @Override
   public int getCount() {

   return this.arrayList.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {

   return arrayList.get(position);
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {

   return position;
   }

   @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leavesummary, null);
       TextView types = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewtypes);
       TextView startDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewstartDate);
       TextView endDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewendDate);
       TextView leavetype = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewleaveType);
       TextView noOfDays = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewnoOfDays);
       TextView reason = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewreason);



       Leave leave = arrayList.get(position);
       types.setText(leave.getTypes());
       startDate.setText(leave.getStartDate());
       endDate.setText(leave.getEndDate());
       leavetype.setText(leave.getLeaves());
       noOfDays.setText(leave.getNoOfDays());
       reason.setText(leave.getReason());

   return convertView;
          }
          }
   ```
3. listleave.xml **Over here I'm using ConstraintLayout**

   ```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

      <ListView

   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/leaveApplicationSummary">
   </ListView>

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   ```
4. leaveSummary.xml

   ```
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/background">
       <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Leave Application Summary"
       android:textColor="#080808"
       android:textSize="20dp"/>
   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
   android:text="Applicant Name :"
   android:textColor="#080808"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textViewApplicantName"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="188dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="188dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
   android:text="Huzaifa  [001]"
   android:textColor="#080808"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
   android:text="Type of Leave :"
   android:textColor="#080808"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textViewtypes"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
   android:text="TextView"
   android:textColor="#080808"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView3"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
   android:text="Leave Start Date :"
   android:textColor="#080808"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textViewstartDate"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="188dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="188dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
   android:text="TextView"
   android:textColor="#080808"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView4"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="208dp"
   android:text="Rejoining Date :"
   android:textColor="#080808"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textViewendDate"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="208dp"
   android:text="TextView"
   android:textColor="#080808"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView5"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="248dp"
   android:text="Leave Type :"
   android:textColor="#080808"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textViewleaveType"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="248dp"
   android:text="TextView"
   android:textColor="#080808"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView6"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="288dp"
   android:text="Total Days Applied :"
   android:textColor="#080808"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textViewnoOfDays"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="216dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="216dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="288dp"
   android:text="TextView"
   android:textColor="#080808"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView7"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="332dp"
   android:text="Remarks :"
   android:textColor="#080808"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textViewreason"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="144dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="144dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="332dp"
   android:text="TextView"
   android:textColor="#080808"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="bottom"
   android:layout_margin="15dp"
   android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <Button
       android:id="@+id/delete"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="Delete" />

       <Button
       android:id="@+id/edit"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="Edit" />
      </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <Button
           android:id="@+id/back"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="Back" />
         </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
       </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   ```
5. apply_leave.xml

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
         tools:context=".ApplyLeave">

       <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout"
         android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <CheckBox
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/GoingAbroad"
           android:hint="Going Abroad"
           android:inputType="text"
           />
   </LinearLayout>
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="Need Advance Payment?"/>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <Spinner
           android:id="@+id/types"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:entries="@array/types"
           />
   </LinearLayout>
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="Leave Type"/>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <Spinner
           android:id="@+id/Leaves"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:entries="@array/leaves"
           />
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <EditText
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/noOfDays"
           android:hint="No. of Days"
           android:inputType="number"/>

   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <Button
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/addField"
           android:text="+"/>
       <Button
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/removeField"
           android:text="-" />
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="Leave starts on" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/startDate"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:clickable="true"
           android:editable="false"
           android:hint="Select" />
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="Rejoining will be on" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/endDate"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:clickable="true"
           android:editable="false"
           android:hint="Select" />

   </LinearLayout>
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/reason"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="Remarks" />
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/days"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Total leave days = 0"/>
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/date"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Leave ends on = "/>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_margin="15dp"
       android:gravity="bottom">

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="Cancel" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/apply"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="Apply" />
          </LinearLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
   ```

   Please tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `l1` should be RecyclerView, not ListView. Try to use RecyclerView instead of ListView and try again

Comment: Where do I put RecyclerView?

Comment: Would you please share your XML with your question?

Comment: post activity_apply_leave.xml

Comment: Sure I'll post the xml layout

Comment: what is your database class..? in myDb you are creating object of LeaveService class. Is LeaveService your db Class?

Comment: Post your database class.. your object of myDb is null..as per my observation

Comment: Yes my class is called leave service

Comment: Please post `activity_apply_leave.xml`

Comment: Ok @FaysalAhmed

Comment: Umm can I send you the xml layout through emai @FaysalAhmed

Comment: I think you called loadDataInListView() method before you set refference to l1, which is in onCreate method. Try to create and set adapter in onCreate. In loadDataInListView only notify adapter of changes...

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I posted the apply leave.xml please check\

Comment: @MarkWalczak How do I do that?

Comment: Move this lines of code 
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,arrayList);
    l1.setAdapter(customAdapter); to onCreate();

Comment: @MarkWalczak I moved them to onCreate but when i'm running my app it stilll crashes

Comment: @Huzaifa Yusuf Did it help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194705/discussion-between-huzaifa-yusuf-and-markwalczak).

Comment: @MarkWalczak It didn't help I moved them to onCreate and when I run the app it still crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting null `l1`.

Confirm your id of ListView in your activity_apply_leave.xml. It should be `leaveApplicationSummary`.

**EDIT:**

Your ListView is in `listleave.xml` but you are using `activity_apply_leave.xml` in your `Activity`.

Move your ListView from `listleave.xml` to `activity_apply_leave.xml`.

Comment: I posted my xml layout for list view please check

Comment: Ok I moved the listview in my apply_leave.xml and it's working

Comment: @HuzaifaYusuf Now thats a new question.